# Django - how to retrieve object by foreign key only?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model PredictorSetterItem, which has a foreign key pointing to PredictorSetter model:

```
class PredictorSetterItem(models.Model):
predictor_setter = models.ForeignKey(PredictorSetter, null=False, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="predictors")
```

When PredictorSetterItem is created, it's assigned a PredictorSetter model in the following way:

```
pdi = PredictorSetterItem()
pdi.predictor_setter = predictor_setter
```

so, as I understand, predictor_setter inside PredictorSetterItem, while being a ForeignKey, points to one and only one PredictorSetter object, so one PredictorSetter can be pointed by multiple PredictorSetterItems, but each PredictorSetterItem has one and only one associated PredictorSetter.

My question is - how do I retrieve PredictorSetter object back? I can't directly get it's attributes via predictor_setter.attribute statements from inside PredictorSetterItem object. So I need to formulate a QuerySet and get the model, but I have no idea how to do that. I don't know primary key or any another attribute of PredictorSetter to filter, but this should be unnecessary, since PredictorSetterItem is associated with one and only one PredictorSetter object.

Comment: If you save `pdi` to the database (`pdi.save()`), and you later load that `PredictorSetterItem` object back, for example as `mypredictorsetteritem`, you can fetch it by that attribute, so `mypredictorsetteritem.predictor_setter`. Django will then make a database query, and load the corresponding `PredictorSetter` object from the database.

Comment: But how can you do it from the inside of PredictorSetterItem? I tried self.predictor_setter, but it references ForeignKey object, not PredictorSetter object.

Comment: if you use this in methods, it will be a `PredictorSetterItem` object. Some IDE's however do not interpret Django's metaclass logic correctly and will fail to understand how this retrieves an object. In PyCharm Professional you can get Django support and it thus will reason about the type correctly.

Comment: Let me understand, have you tried: `pdi.predictor_setter.all()`?